# Javascript regex how to get all occurences between two words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using the following function in order to get the string between two words in a string:

```
function findStringBetween(str,first,last){
  var r = new RegExp(first+'.*(.*)'+last,'gm');
  var a = str.match(r);     
  return a;
}
```

But I can not get all occurences of the possible findings.

For example if a sentence (str) like this is the case:

*"The sentence which has a lot of words inside. The sentence short inside. And some other sentence to fill this example of mine."*

I get this:

```
var found = findStringBetween(str, 'The', 'inside');
>> ["The sentence which has a lot of words inside. The sentence short inside"]
```

What I'd like to get is all occurances of findings between the two words "The" and "inside". For the example result would be:

```
>> ["The sentence which has a lot of words inside",
>> "The sentence short inside"]
```

Is this possible via regex? if it is not, what can I do to make a fast finding?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the last item be two separate items?

Comment: sorry, the example was a bit misleading. I changed the variables.

Comment: "A" would match lots of possibilities.

Comment: ok between "The" and "inside" how many boundary possibilities can there be for this string?

Comment: In that case, please check my first comment.

Comment: The last item as two seperate items are in a[0] and a[1]? Also the other boundary as a[2]? I broke them to multilines to make it easy to read.

Comment: Shouldn't `"The sentence which has a lot of words inside. The sentence short inside"` be two different strings in the result?

Comment: It would do for my purposes. Maybe there is no other way...

Comment: I mean for the logic, the last item also matches the rule being in between "The" and "inside".

Comment: Let me try the same question in another way. How many `The` and `inside` are there in that string?

Comment: ok let me delete the last item.

Comment: No, what I mean is, the pattern is not clear. You havn't explained that in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The problem is that the regex character "*" (and "+") is "greedy" by default, meaning it will go with the longest possible match. You want the shortest possible match, so make it "lazy" by adding a "?" after it, like so:

```
function findStringBetween(str, first, last) {
    var r = new RegExp(first + '(.*?)' + last, 'gm');
    return str.match(r);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. m="@test:asas :mask:"
m.match(/:(.*?):/gm) gives only asas. Should also give mask

Comment: @red-devil please don't downvote me because my solution to a problem other than yours doesn't also happen to solve your problem. The solution to your problem—finding the string between occurrences of one delimiter, rather than between two delimiters—is `:(.*?)(?=:)` (for delimiter `:`).

Comment: @twhb Your example above how can I exclude the first and last delimiters in the matched group?

Comment: @BiJ I can't figure out a way to do it in JS because JS regular expressions don't have lookbehinds. If they did, it would be `\`(?<=${first}).*?(?=${last})\``. As is, an alternative is to take only the content of the first matching group by replacing the last line with `return r.exec(str)[1];`.